# French canadian keyboard layout

Tags: macos, keyboard

Is there a way to configure my keyboard layout in Lion to match the Windows "Français (Canada)" (or French (Canada) if you prefer!) layout?

Currently, I use the french canadian layout from Mac OS on my MacBook Pro. It's not the same as the Windows one. For instance, the pipe "|" on my macbookpro is something like "Command" + "-", and on my windows machine is mapped to the left of "1".

I do not wish to make my MBP a Windows machine or anything like that, just that I'm used to that keyboard layout for many years while programming and it's hard to switch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele) to create your own keyboard layouts, or (more realistically) edit a copy of an existing one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly the kind of thing I needed! I switched to Mac some months ago, and the keyboard layout was holding me back to program at my full speed. Old habits die hard!

Answer (score 1):

There is a custom [French Canadian](https://github.com/ergosteur/cf-keylayout) keyboard shared on github.

I am using it for years.